Is every Borel probability measure on Lindel$ӧ$f space $\tau$-additive?
It is well-known that every Borel measure on hereditarily Lindel$ӧ$f space X is $\tau$-additive, since we can extract countable subcover of every open cover of every subset of X and then apply $\sigma$-additivity to get $\tau$-additivity.
Now I am reading "Topological measure theory for completely
regular spaces and their projective covers" by Robert F. Wheeler (1979), where only Baire measures on completely regular spaces are considered. Here it is stated that the space X is defined as measure-compact if the space of $\sigma$-additive measures on it coincides with the space of $\tau$-additive measures, and for that to occur it is sufficient for X to be Lindel$ӧ$f.
Is that true for Borel measures, that it is sufficient for X to be Lindel$ӧ$f, but not hereditarily Lindel$ӧ$f?
And why is it true for Baire measures? Could someone please give me reference to this fact?
P.S.: If someone is interested, I found it in the "Measure theory", Volume 4 by D.H. Fremlin: 434H Proposition, b (p.188).

What does $\tau$-additive mean?

@PatrickR Borel probability measure $\mu$ on topological space $X$ is called $\tau$-additive, if for every increasing net of open sets $(U_\lambda){\lambda \in \Lambda}$:
$\mu (\underset{\lambda \in \Lambda}\cup U\lambda) = \underset{\lambda}\lim \mu( U_\lambda).$
It means that measure is regular with respect to topology of the space $X$, interacting well with it in the sense of definition.
